# Unable to deploy Alfresco war community edition on JBOSS

Tags: jboss, alfresco

I have downloaded Alfresco community edition for POC purposes and it comes with tomcat by default. I want to deploy the Alfresco war (which comes with community edition) in JBOSS , but I am unable to do so . Kindly help.

Comment: What have you tried when installing on JBoss? Which instructions did you follow? What error message are you getting?

Comment: We added the Alfresco share war and alfresco war available in the Community edition setup and deployed in the deployment folder . It shows no error as well. Is it like we can only deploy Alfresco enterprise edition on JBOSS ?

Comment: As broad generalisation, Alfresco Community works with a pure open-source stack. As soon as you want to start using it with expensive paid-for components (eg expensive databases or app servers), you need to also pay Alfresco a tiny fraction of that money in license fees for Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: 
Alfresco on JBoss EAP 6.1
http://www.jbossauthority.com/alfresco-on-jboss-eap-6-1/

and here http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/installation-upgrades/jboss-war-deployment